# scala what does this mean? "{ /* compiled code */ }"

Tags: scala

I came across this thing multiple times: `{ /* compiled code */ }` but I can't find what it does in scala.

example:

```
object autoImport extends scala.AnyRef {
    ...
    val destination : sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File] = { /* compiled code */ }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't do anything. It's your IDE telling you that it can't find the source code for the given method and thus can't show it to you.

That's assuming you're looking at a class file in your IDE. If you're looking at actual Scala code, it's just an empty method with a severely misleading comment.

Comment: thanks, it make more sense now, I thought it might be some obscure scala sugar