# Scala. Empty definitions DEF = {/* compiled code */} in .class files from ,Jar

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, sbt

I'am trying to understand how `:=` method works in build.sbt file.

With intellij idea you can use left click + ctrl to find definiton of object.
But in *SettingCase.class* file all methods described as `{ /* compiled code */ }`.

So i wondering if there is no code. How compiler understands how to use this methods?

[image: .class with empty definitions]

[image: build.sbt file with := method]

Already searched several articles with this topic like [this_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099372/scala-what-does-this-mean-compiled-code)
and [this_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286659/scala-decompiled-code-has-stub-compiled-code)
But there is no answer for my question.

Comment: Well, the link you posted do explain the _compiled code_ thing. If you want to have a look to the code, check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/973cd63e0b6bfe0d06d364f314f391a08a77d38b/main-settings/src/main/scala/sbt/Structure.scala#L57

Comment: The main point I want to understand - how compiler understands how to use this methods if they are not defined (empty)

Comment: `:=` is a macro. Maybe IntellIJ has trouble showing macro definitions? In any case, `:=` is defined, as seen in the code Gaël linked. It is not “empty”.

Comment: @SethTisue it's not about macros.

All functions in .class files in _External Libraries_ have empty declaration i.e `{ /* compiled code */ }`

I can find source code on GitHub by my self. But i want to understand how copiler understands how to process this functions.

Comment: **The compiler sees the already compiled code (you only pull compiled code, not source code) and it's fine with it.** It's just IntelliJ that for some reason is not able to show the decompiled code because of some reason we're not sure about.

Comment: @GaëlJ That makes sense. I get the idea. Thank you for your help!